# Yii2 concatenate a variable to String in whenClient

Tags: javascript, yii2, string-concatenation, validationrules

I am using a dynamic form with validation rules and I want to make the browser validate also the form before it submit so I used `whenClient`. There is a checkbox that when clicked, will not process validation...

```
['dv_number', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->is_cancelled == 1;
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {  
            console.log(attribute.name);
            var firstletter=(attribute.name.charAt(0));
            var index='';
            if(firstletter==='['){ //when dynamic form is not activated and name of inputs is like [0]dv_number
                index=attribute.name.charAt(1);//I get the array index
            }else{
                index=attribute.name.charAt(9);//dynamic form activated the name of inputs changed like this TblDvBub[0][dv_number].
            }

            if($('[name=\'TblDvBub[0][is_cancelled][]\']').is(\":checked\"))
            {
                return false;//validation will not take place
            }
            else
            {
                return true;//validation from browser takes place
            }

        }"
    ],
```

So I get the index number using the `index` variable. My problem is to replace the `0` in this line `if($('[name=\'TblDvBub[0][is_cancelled][]\']').is(\":checked\"))` to index and make it like this `if($('[name=\'TblDvBub[index][is_cancelled][]\']').is(\":checked\"))`

NOTE that the whole code starting from when client is enclosed by `" "`...

I have tried this and a lot others but to no avail.

```
if($('[name=\'TblDvBub[' + index +'][is_cancelled][]\']').is(\":checked\"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a JS/jQuery/PHP issue. You have to escape the brackets in the name filter of the selector:

```js
if($('[name=TblDvBub\\[' + index + '\\]\\[is_cancelled\\]\\[\\]]').is(\":checked\"))
```

Not quite sure, but when this is within a "" string in PHP you have to even double the escaping characters:

```js
if($('[name=TblDvBub\\\\[' + index + '\\\\]\\\\[is_cancelled\\\\]\\\\[\\\\]]').is(\":checked\"))
```

I think this is the problem here. Does it help? Is the first or second way correct?

See [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (noted in the starting paragraph).

Comment: wow.. The first one doesn't work but the second is a lucky charm.. Thanks a lot..